# Javascript - Google API GET: Value null outside google api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, redux, undefined

I am making a call to Google Calendar API for a specific event and am able to get the recurrence value.

```
  function getRecurrence(payload) {
    console.log('payload = ' + payload);
    var recurrence = '';
    if (payload != undefined) {
      var requestRecurringEvent = window.gapi.client.calendar.events.get({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'eventId': payload
      });
      requestRecurringEvent.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log('requestRecurringEvent = ' + resp);
        console.log('requestRecurringEvent.recurrence = ' + resp.recurrence);
        recurrence = resp.recurrence;

        console.log('recurrence (inside execute)= ' + recurrence); //NO ISSUE (YET): recurrence (inside execute) = RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10

        return recurrence;
      });
    } else {
      return 'no recurrence value';
    }
  }
```

However, when I return the recurrence value to a variable

```
var recurrence = getRecurrence(action.payload.calendarEventRecurringEventId);
console.log('recurrence (outside execute) = ' + recurrence);  //ISSUE: recurrence (outside execute) = undefined
```

*note: `action.payload.calendarEventRecurringEventId` is because I am passing in the value from payload in redux.*

**Why is the value defined inside the api call but undefined outside the api call??**

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Promises seem to have taken me in the right direction, since the `console.log('recurrence (outside execute) = ' + recurrence)` prints a value, but it seems to not have completely solved the problem since an empty string is still being set for the value in redux.

```
var recurrencePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var payload = action.payload.calendarEventRecurringEventId;
      console.log('action.payload.calendarEventRecurringEventId = ' + payload);
      var recurrence = '';
      if (payload != undefined) {
        console.log('getRecurrence payload != undefined');
        var requestRecurringEvent = window.gapi.client.calendar.events.get({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'eventId': payload
        });
        requestRecurringEvent.execute(function(resp) {
          console.log('requestRecurringEvent = ' + resp);
          console.log('requestRecurringEvent.recurrence = ' + resp.recurrence);
          recurrence = resp.recurrence;
          console.log('recurrence (inside execute)= ' + recurrence);
          resolve(recurrence);
        });
      } else {
        reject(Error("It broke"));
      }
    });

    recurrencePromise.then(function(recurrence) {
      console.log('recurrence (outside execute) = ' + recurrence);
      var recurrenceTemp = 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10';
      return {
        ...state,
        calendarEventEndDate: action.payload.calendarEventEndDate,
        calendarEventEndDateTime: action.payload.calendarEventEndDateTime,
        calendarEventEndTime: action.payload.calendarEventEndTime,
        calendarEventID: action.payload.calendarEventID,
        calendarEventTitle: action.payload.calendarEventTitle,
        calendarEventRecurringEventId: defaultIfUndefined(action.payload.calendarEventRecurringEventId, ''),
        calendarEventRecurrence: recurrence, //ISSUE: this is where the value should be something like `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10` instead of `''`
      }
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
    });
```

**Why is the right value still not set defined outside the api call?**

Answer (score 0):

Because the `requestRecurringEvent.execute` function is asynchronous, which means you can never tell when the asynchronous function completes its execution (returns) unlike a synchronous function that guaranties a return value, async doesnt. What you need to do if you want to use the recurrence value outside is, A) Use a callback function B) use Promises (which I am sure the google api call provides by default)

I recommend you read more about asynchronity in javascript, to have a grasp on how it works.

Comment: I have updated my question with attempt using Promises.  Unfortunately, the value from the api call is still not being set to redux.  Any idea why? @eersteam